# Background color of selected DataGridRow not working / how to combine with AlternationIndex?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to style a `DataGrid`, this includes styling `DataGridRow` as well. What I want is having an alternating background behavior on my rows (say, White/Grey); when a row is selected, the background should be YellowGreen. Somehow the following code is not working, but I'm sure using DataGridCell for the selection part would work; I'd just like to know why this isn't doing it:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource EnBWLichtgrau}"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
      </Trigger>
      <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Property="DataGridRow.AlternationIndex" Value="0"/>
          <Condition Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
      </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource EnBWAnthrazitgrau}"/>
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
  </Style>
```

Maybe some setters override the MultiTrigger setters, maybe something else, I don't know. The MultiTrigger isn't really necessary right now, but even a simple Trigger on IsSelected doesn't work this way.

As I said, I could probably go over to styling DataGridCell, but the "why" is what I'm interested in :-) Thanks!

**EDIT:** I tried using `DataGridCell` instead for the `IsSelected` part and it works as expected. But what if I wanted the selected row background color to be different depending on the AlternationIndex of the `DataGridRow` the cell is in? Is there some way to get the value of this index inside the `DataGridCell` style definition e.g.?

Comment: I am having this same issue with ListBoxItem. It appears as though AlternationIndex trigger is fired AFTER IsSelected trigger, or IsSelected is completely circumvented by AlternationIndex trigger. Can we can an update from someone about how to bypass this?